# Lookup Value in Same Column on Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

In column B on three (Bakery, Floral, Grocery) of the five sheets in my workbook, I want to find rows that have the word `Flyer` in column B. There will be multiple rows in each worksheet that have the word `Flyer` in column B. When it finds the word `Flyer`, it will paste the entire row into Sheet1.

I go this to work on one tab, but want the same code to search all three tabs (but NOT all five ... this is the issue) and paste all of the rows with the word `Flyer` in column B into Sheet1.

My code (works, but only on the Bakery tab):

```
Sub CopyRowsFlyer()
'This looks in the Bakery tab and moves everything that has "Flyer" in     column B to Sheet 1
  Dim bottomB As Integer
  Dim x As Integer
  bottomB = Sheets("Bakery").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1

  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Sheets("Bakery").Range("B3:B" & bottomB)
    If c.Value = "Flyer" Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other solutions posted. Pretty simple. Replaces bounding for range checking. Fewest variables. No mid-execution dimensioning.

```
Sub CopyRowsFlyer()
  Dim strSh As Variant, c As Range, x As Integer
  x = 1

  For Each strSh In Array("Bakery", "Floral", "Grocery")
    For Each c In Worksheets(strSh).Range("B:B")
      If c = "" and c.Row > 2 Then
        Exit For
      ElseIf c = "Flyer" and c.Row > 2 Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Fixed to skip the first two rows.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only one that worked as planned. The others worked, but as it moved from worksheet to worksheet, it would write over the previously found rows in Sheet 1. For example, if there were 7 rows found in the bakery tab with "Flyer" in column B (and those rows were copied to Sheet 1), and 3 rows found/copied in the Floral tab, then Sheet one would only contain 7 rows total. The first 3 rows were the rows from Floral and the bottom 4 were from Bakery.

Comment: Your welcome! The key to keeping the row placement is your idea!; the `x = x + 1`. I just built some stuff around it :)

Comment: This code had been working great, but when someone rolled the workbook over to a new month, the error message box "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" keeps coming up. I've made sure everything is named appropriately (tab, spelling of promotions, etc), but can not figure out a solution to this error.

Answer (score 1):

Store the desired worksheet names in an array and loop through them.

```
Sub CopyRowsFlyer()
    Dim bottomB As Long, b As Long, x As Long
    Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant
    vWSs = Array("Bakery", "Floral", "Grocery")

    x = 1
    For w = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
        With Worksheets(vWSs(w))
            bottomB = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For b = 3 To bottomB
                If LCase(.Cells(b, "B").Value) = "flyer" Then
                    .Rows(b).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & x)
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next b
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

While this method of looping through the cells in each worksheet's column B is considered inefficient compared to other methods like the [.Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx), it will not make a lot of difference on smaller sets of data. If you have a large number of rows on each worksheet to examine, you may wish to explore other more direct avenues of retrieving the information.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to loop through the three sheets you want.  Try this:

```
 Sub CopyRowsFlyer()
 'This looks in the Bakery tab and moves everything that has "Flyer" in     column B to Sheet 1
   Dim bottomB As Integer
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim SheetsArray() As Variant
   Dim ws As WorkSheet
   Dim i As Integer       

   SheetsArray = Array("Bakery", "Sheet2Name", "Sheet3Name")
   For i = LBound(SheetsArray) To UBound(SheetsArray)
        Set ws = Sheets(SheetsArray(i))
        bottomB = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1

        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In ws.Range("B3:B" & bottomB)
              If c.Value = "Flyer" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & x)
                    x = x + 1
              End If
        Next c
   Next i
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute an element of a string array for the ID in Sheets.

Here is your code modified to reflect.

```
Sub CopyRowsFlyer()
  Dim bottomB As Integer
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim sheetName(1 to 3) As String, i as Integer
  sheetName(1) = "Bakery"
  sheetName(2) = "Floral"
  sheetName(3) = "Grocery"
  x=1
  For i = 1 to 3
    bottomB = Sheets(sheetName(i)).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Sheets(sheetName(i)).Range("B3:B" & bottomB)
        If c.Value = "Flyer" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & x)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next c
  Next i
End Sub
```